# Visual Studio setup project "PackageAs" "extremely loose"

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

We were hoping to create a setup project which would allow for a pick-n-mix approach to which files were included for each local client installation.

Basically we've got a core setup.exe which we only want to build once, and which contains most of the product. But for each client there's a custom DLL which fits their solution. The custom DLL is loaded dynamically at runtime by the software and that's working fine. The problem is in the setup.

Of course we could 1) write an individual custom Setup.exe for each client too 2) keep a single setup.exe and customise it each time we want to do a build for the customer

But both those approaches are problematic.

For reasons too complicated to go into, the below approach is going to be the safest and most straightforward:

1. Maintain a single setup project
2. add all the custom DLLs to the setup project but set them to **PackageAs=Loose** (and also **Vital=False**)
3. then, every time we want to rollout the install files to the customer we send the setup files minus all the custom DLLs except his own

Our problem is that this approach falls down when you run the setup.exe on the client. Everything's fine except that the setup.exe *still knows* about all the DLLs you've quietly removed from the file system for this customer. And the installer starts shouting if it doesn't find all the files where it expects to find them:

[image]

Actually, this isn't a problem because you can hit **Continue** and then everything works fine.

*Except* that actually it **is** a problem because if you're selling to Pepsi (we're not, but say we were) you sort of don't want the installer to moan that it can't find CocaCola.foo.dll in the middle of its install.

We almost want an additional setting of **Extremely Loose** for the **PackageAs** field so that the installer knows not to even worry if it doesn't find the file.

Is there a solution within our existing approach without having to learn a third-party installer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your optional components should be created as [Merge Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then you'd need a specific installer created that includes only certain modules.  It sounds like you have some client specific libraries you don't want exposed to your other clients.  Of course this means you'll need a build for each client, but that is something that could be automated.